# How to resolve "Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)"

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to connect my flutter app with firebase, I have tired all the available solutions, yet I keep getting the followign error

```
**E/flutter ( 1955): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)**
```

I installed all the packages and tried to initialize firebase on my main.dart file

```
Future main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```